# Sequelize - dateonly vs date format

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

If I store timestamp `1625555827900` in 2 separate fields whose format are `dateonly` and `date`,
will there be any difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not store the unix timestamps in both of the fields as their types are DATEONLY and DATE. Sequelize will through an error

```
DatabaseError [SequelizeDatabaseError]: date/time field value out of range: "1625555827900"
```

First you need to format the date like `Tue Jul 06 2021 07:55:33` or `2021-07-06 07:55:33` in your code. In that case, it will save the complete date `2021-07-06 07:55:33.000000` for DATE field and skip the time part for DATEONLY field `2021-07-06`.

Or you can use BIGINT instead if you are intended to store the unix timestamps.

Comment: What if I store `Tue Jul 06 2021 07:55:33` in both field?

Comment: For DATEONLY, it will only save the date part and skip the time and for DATE, it will save the complete date with time.